# mysqldump with partitioned table

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a large MyiSam table and I recently partitioned it. I backup the db every day usng mysqldump but rather than bakcup the entire large table, I'd like to just backup certain partition(s).  Is there any way that I can specify which partitions to dump using mysqldump?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use select statement, because mysqldump has no way to know the name of the partition.

Comment: Is there any syntax like "Copy table" which copies just the partition that I want. From what I understand you can drop partitions like tables, is there any way you can replicate them like tables?

Comment: No, but you wont need that. Just use select statement like this example : http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/mysql_select_into_file.php